# Install Jupyter from Pycharm console

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install Jupyter Notebook from the PyCharm console, but got the following error.

```
/usr/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" 62076 62077
PyDev console: starting.

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/Users/edamame/Documents/git/HelloWorld'])

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
>>> pip install jupyter
  File "<input>", line 1
    pip install jupyter
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `pip` isn't meant to be ran from the Python REPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I noticed that you tagged your question Python3.

Notice in the output there, `Python 2.7.10`.

So, I'm guessing you have python3 setup externally... Be careful with this because dependencies are not shared

So, you need to use the *Terminal* of the IDE (or your OS), and then

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

The `>>>` prompt is the Python REPL, not the OS command line

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run pip on python shell.It is a **program** that installs modules, so you can use them from Python.
Run pip on your terminal.

```
vibhutha@vibhutha-pc:~$ pip install jupytor
```

PS - Its better install jupytor-notebook from anaconda package manager.
[More details](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: Anaconda is very large just in order to get Jupyter

Comment: Jupytor-notebook is a very useful in data science. So install anaconda will automatically installs other essential python packages. And no need virtualenv.

Comment: I don't exactly consider numpy/pandas, and all that essential for strictly having Jupyter available. Miniconda is my recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import pip` and follow below commands to install pip packages in the **python shell**.

```
>>> import pip
>>> package = 'jupytor'
>>> pip.main(['install', package])
```